# Python: Which would be a better programming practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I learnt about **DRY** code and

> Flat is better than nested

I also know that excessively DRY code is bad and I am not "religiously" DRY or anything. But which of these would be better? (I can't make out as the creator what might be less readable)

```
"""
Basically the variable "answer" is overwritten to equal "number" "+" or "-"
or "*" or "/" or "**" the existing value of answer. Here, operation is a 
dictionary; and a value (such as to add, subtract etc.) is accessed based on
symbol the user has inputted (such as "+", "-" etc.)
"""     

#Type 1:    

number = float(input("Enter number: "))
answer = operation[symbol](answer, number)

#Type 2:

answer = operation[symbol](answer, (float(input("Enter number: "))))
```

Comment: If you've got two large pieces of code, you might want to calculate them separately and save references. If they're not too large, there's no need to save references. Follow PEP-8 and use your judgement.

Comment: There isn't even a difference in DRYness or flatness here. It's only a difference between ***inlining*** a function call or keeping it in a separate statement. 1 is easier to read, 2 is terser. Choose the more appropriate style for your situation.

Comment: How's the question related to DRY or "Flat is better than nested" though?  Neither of the options has repeated code nor indentation.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen it's dry cuz I'm otherwise repeating a variable I'm using only once (that's taking up 2 times the code) and it's nested cuz as you can see at the end of **Type 2**, there's **4** ")"'s.

Comment: "Nested" typically refers to nested control structures, e.g. `if foo: if bar: while baz: for x in y: ...`. This does not apply here. And you're not repeating any code here; you're *creating* one variable and then *use* it. That's not repetition. WET repetition is writing the same block of code expressing the same business logic multiple times.

Comment: @NeelKamath As @deceze said, repeating the name of a variable is not what DRY refers to. When you do the same calculation (or any other *statement*) multiple times, that's actual repetition. Variables are the opposite of repetition, if you ever need your `number` again, it's already stored in a variable and you don't have to repeat yourself by writing `float(input("Enter number: "))` again (although `input()` isn't the best example here). You should read [DRY on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) :)

Comment: @deceze @NeelKamath While it's true that ["`Flat is better than nested`"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) usually refers to the nested `for`s, `if`s, and `while`s, it **does** actually make sense in OP's context too. I would totally prefer having a separate variable even if it's only used once, as oppsoed to a long statement of nested function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its greate that you think about software quality right from the start. The best answer is not always very clear, and especially if you consider a decision on a very low level of a single instruction call, as you do now.
I would vote for Type1, but Type2 is also entirely OK. This is dependent on person's habits that develop over time.
I think you can go with any of them for now, but still consider best practices and design patterns when thinking about the overall shape of your program. The goal is for software to be easily **maintainable** and (in case you create a library) **easy to use** by other programmers.

Comment: "I would vote for Type1, but Type1 is also entirely OK." I feel like this guy supports Type1 over Type2.

Comment: I disagree, type 1 is clearly better than type 1.

Comment: @deceze Anything to justify that claim?

Comment: @Markus Meskanen : thanks for indicating my typo; corrected. You discovered my deepest thoughts :-)

Comment: @Donkey Dad jokes mustn't be justified.

Comment: OK thx. I was going to go with Type 2, but everyone here is preferring Type 1 (and @Mrs. Bean showed that if I come back to the code much later, it would be confusing).

Answer (score -2):

This example is not so complicated, so type 2 would be Okay (but meh) for me, but overall I would go for type 1 because I think it is more readable. Not just for me, but also for everyone else who will be working with my code later. I don't like the multiple actions in one line, I think it makes things unnecessarily complicated when you (or someone else) come back to it later

Comment: Why the downvotes though...?

Comment: I was wondering why this whole post had only downvotes, I guess I should stick with Quora or something for random questions like this

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I was wondering the same thing.. It's not that long but it's all I wanted to add on the matter, so. Oh well, you win some, you lose some, I guess